# How to get rid of phantom row in array?

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, nokogiri

I'm scraping a bunch of tables with httparty, then parsing the response with nokogiri. Everything works well, but then I get a phantom row at the top:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'
require 'byebug'
def scraper
    url = "https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis"
    parsed_page = Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(url))
    # Get categories from the ul at the top
    categories = parsed_page.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div/div/article/ul/li/a')
    # Get all tables from the page
    tables = parsed_page.xpath('/html/body/div[4]/div/main/div[2]/div/div/div/article/table')
    rows = []
    # Acting on one first for testing before making it dynamic 
    tables[0].search('tr').each do |tr|
        cells = tr.search('td')
        link = ''
        values = []
        row = {
            'name' => '',
            'description' => '',
            'auth' => '',
            'https' => '',
            'cors' => '',
            'category' => '',
            'url' => ''
        }
        cells.css('a').each do |a|
            link += a['href']
        end
        cells.each do |cell|
            values << cell.text
        end
        values << categories[0].text
        values << link
        rows << row.keys.zip(values).to_h
    end
    puts rows
end
scraper
```

Result in console:

```
{"name"=>"Animals", "description"=>"", "auth"=>nil, "https"=>nil, "cors"=>nil, "category"=>nil, "url"=>nil}
{"name"=>"Cat Facts", "description"=>"Daily cat facts", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", 
...
```

Where is that first row coming from?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages. When asking for help on a problem like this we need the absolute minimum code that demonstrates the problem, along with the minimum input data _in the question itself_. Asking us to retrieve the HTML page, scan through it to determine the area you're having problems with reduces the number of people who will help, so help us help you.

Comment: It's not good to use absolute/full paths to a node, either in XPath or CSS. Instead, find way-points to use to navigate to the node you want. _When_ the markup changes, an absolute path will break, but odds are good that skipping through looking for specific node patterns will succeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first row you're seeing is most likely the header row. Header rows use `<th>` instead of `<td>`. This means `cells = tr.search('td')` will be an empty collection for the header row.

In most cases header rows are placed in the `<thead>` and data rows are placed in `<tbody>`. So instead of doing `tables[0].search('tr')` you could be doing `tables[0].search('tbody tr')`, which only selects rows in the `<tbody>` tag.

Comment: Welp, I was sure as hell I was already targeting tbody, this is embarrassing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: `thead`, `tbody`, while they are _supposed_ to be there, don't exist in the majority of documents on the web, because those were created before they were added or because the creators of the documents didn't care. Browsers add them automatically and display them when we look at the source, but relying on the browser's rendered source often causes a selector to fail if those nodes don't actually exist in the source file. It's always good to use `wget`, `curl` or `nokogiri` at the command-line to view the true markup and ignore what the browser says.

Answer (score 1):

Your code could be much simpler and more resilient:

Meditate on this:

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'httparty'

URL = 'https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis'
FIELDS = %w[name description auth https cors category url]

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(HTTParty.get(URL))

category = doc.at('article li a').text

rows = doc.at('article table').search('tr')[1..-1].map { |tr| 
  values = tr.search('td').map(&:text)
  link = tr.at('a')['href']
  Hash[
    FIELDS.zip(values + [category, link])
  ]
}
```

Which results in:

```
puts rows

# >> {"name"=>"Cat Facts", "description"=>"Daily cat facts", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"No", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://alexwohlbruck.github.io/cat-facts/"}
# >> {"name"=>"Cats", "description"=>"Pictures of cats from Tumblr", "auth"=>"apiKey", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://docs.thecatapi.com/"}
# >> {"name"=>"Dogs", "description"=>"Based on the Stanford Dogs Dataset", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Yes", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://dog.ceo/dog-api/"}
# >> {"name"=>"HTTPCat", "description"=>"Cat for every HTTP Status", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://http.cat/"}
# >> {"name"=>"IUCN", "description"=>"IUCN Red List of Threatened Species", "auth"=>"apiKey", "https"=>"No", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"http://apiv3.iucnredlist.org/api/v3/docs"}
# >> {"name"=>"Movebank", "description"=>"Movement and Migration data of animals", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://github.com/movebank/movebank-api-doc"}
# >> {"name"=>"Petfinder", "description"=>"Adoption", "auth"=>"OAuth", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Yes", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://www.petfinder.com/developers/v2/docs/"}
# >> {"name"=>"PlaceGOAT", "description"=>"Placeholder goat images", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://placegoat.com/"}
# >> {"name"=>"RandomCat", "description"=>"Random pictures of cats", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Yes", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://aws.random.cat/meow"}
# >> {"name"=>"RandomDog", "description"=>"Random pictures of dogs", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Yes", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://random.dog/woof.json"}
# >> {"name"=>"RandomFox", "description"=>"Random pictures of foxes", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"No", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://randomfox.ca/floof/"}
# >> {"name"=>"RescueGroups", "description"=>"Adoption", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Unknown", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"https://userguide.rescuegroups.org/display/APIDG/API+Developers+Guide+Home"}
# >> {"name"=>"Shibe.Online", "description"=>"Random pictures of Shibu Inu, cats or birds", "auth"=>"No", "https"=>"Yes", "cors"=>"Yes", "category"=>"Animals", "url"=>"http://shibe.online/"}
```

The issues with your code are:

- Using [`search('some selector')[0]`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#search-instance_method) is the same as [`at('some selector')`](https://nokogiri.org/rdoc/Nokogiri/XML/Searchable.html#at-instance_method) only the second is cleaner resulting in less visual noise.

  There are other, more subtle, differences as far as what `search` returns in comparison to `at`, which is covered in the documentation. I highly recommend reading and experimenting with their examples as knowing which to use when can save you headaches.
- Relying on absolute XPath selectors: An absolute selector is very fragile. Any change to the HTML will have a high-likelihood of breaking. Instead, find useful nodes to check that are unique, and let the parser find them.

  Using a CSS selector `'article li a'` jumps through all the nodes until it finds the "article" node, looks inside it for the child "li" and following "a". You *can* do the same thing with XPath, but it's visually noisy. I'm a big fan of keeping my code as easy to read and comprehend as possible.

  Similarly, `at('article table')` finds the first table under the "article" node, then `search('tr')` finds the embedded rows in only that table.

  Because you want to skip the table header `[1..-1]` slices the NodeSet and skips that first row.
- [`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) makes it easier to build a structure:

  ```
  rows = doc.at('article table').search('tr')[1..-1].map { |tr|
  ```

  assigns the fields to `rows` in one pass through that loop of rows.

  `values` is assigned with the text of the NodeSet of every "td" node's text.
- You can easily build a hash by using [Hash's `[]`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Hash.html#method-c-5B-5D) constructor and passing in an array of key/value pairs.

  ```
  FIELDS.zip(values + [category, link])
  ```

  is taking the values from the cells and adding a second array containing the category and link from the row.

My example code is basically the same template *every* time I scrape a page with a table. There'll be minor differences, but it's a loop over the table extracting the cells and converting them to a hash. It's even possible, on a cleanly written table, to automatically grab the keys of the hash from cell text in the first row of the table.